# NagiosGraph not updating custom Map entry since Nagios Upgrade

Tags: nagios

I recently upgraded my Nagios installation from 3.2 to the latest version. After the upgrade everything seemed to be working fine, however I have just noticed today that part of Nagios Graph has stopped working.

I use NRPE to execute a VBS script I wrote on my webservers. The query parses the log files created by IIS and returns the number of GET entries in the last 10 minutes, the returned output is something like:

```
OK: PAGEHITS 403
```

To get this working originally, I edited the map file for Nagios Graph and added the following entry:

```
/output:.*PAGEHITS.*?(\d+)/
and push @s, [ 'pagehits',
            [ 'data', GAUGE, $1 ] ];
```

This always used to work, however I did notice that since the upgrade the map file had gone back to the default, but I replaced it with my modified file containing the entry above and it does not seem to be picking this up. New hosts with this service added are not having a graph generated for them.

All the other graphs are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently nagios no longer emits plugin output to the perfdata file if the plugin does not emit performance data.  please see this thread for details:

http://www.mail-archive.com/nagios-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg36835.html